# Fixed menu with hover submenu a bit off

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, submenu

I'm working on a navbar that has a horizontal menu. On my last element (Select user type) of the menu I would like to include a submenu when the user hovers over it. I managed to get a submenu to appear when hovering over the respective item but it is all the way on the left, instead of right under the item.

I included the code below:
HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="menu">
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
      <li id="dropdown">Select User Type
          <ul>
              <li>Link 1</li>
              <li>Link 2</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color: black;
  color:#fff;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  height:30px;
  padding:0 15px;
  color:#F5F5F5;
  line-height:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#menu li:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
  color:black;
}
#menu li ul {
  display: none;
  width: 10em;
  /* Width to help Opera out */
 background-color: #69f;
}
#menu li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
  float: none;
  background-color: #69f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle link as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ZT6Pq/

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gahathat/7RM76/)

All I changed was the main li position to "relative" and the submenu position to "absolute." This causes the submenu to be positioned relative to its parent li item.

```
#menu li {
    display: inline;
    height:30px;
    padding:0 15px;
    color:#F5F5F5;
    line-height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative; /* New */
}

#menu li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;  /* New */
    top: 24px;  /* New */
    left: 0;    /* New */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add to your #menu li:

```
position: relative;
```

and add top and left to your #menu li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul

```
top:25px;
left:0;
```

here id the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZT6Pq/1/